# How to make a div scale to 100% height inside a vertical scrollable div?

Tags: html, css

I want div2's height to be 100% of div1 even if scrolled down to the bottom-most part (not just 100px).
Is this possible with CSS only?

http://jsfiddle.net/jPMjF/2/

```
<div id="div1">
     <div id="div2">
     </div>
     <p>Bunch of text here</p>
</div>

#div1 {
   background-color: #fff;
   border:1px solid #ff0000;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   width: 200px;
}

#div1 p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
}

#div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ccc;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%
}
```

Comment: its possible via css.. and can also be possible via jquery.. actually is the code not working via css..???

Comment: @forceSD I edited my answer with a few alternatives, but really there is no "pretty way" I can think of to easily achieve this.

Comment: hmm, still can't get the answer that i need.

Answer (score 1):

Why would div1 ever exceed 300px scrollable height if div2 was less than 300px? From what you've posted, I think all you need is:

```
#div1 {
   height: 300px;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: auto;
}

#div2 {
    background-color: #ccc;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

This means div2 fills the entire container when less than 300px height but can still expand should the container overflow with a scrollbar.

**EDIT**

Okay, so it seems this is unsuitable. At this point I would be leaning towards a few situational options:

1. If you know that only one of div2 or p (say we place this within div3) will ever exceed 300px in height then you could set the background of div1 to match the opposite div. This means any white space below the smaller div will have the same background, appearing the same to the user.
2. If both div2 and div3 will have a fixed width then you can clear both backgrounds and just place a background image on the container div. (This would clearly be a vertically repeating 1px strip with a colour split somewhere down the middle.)
3. If you are not catering for older browsers you could use the CSS3 flexible box model, which as I understand it is meant to expand to fill all space within a container.
4. You could use the `display: table` property as a somewhat "hackish" method to table style. Be aware that css tables don't seem to allow fixed heights, they will overflow to show all content without scrollbars, so you will need to place it within an outer container set to inline-block, fixed width with appropriate overflow values.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/jPMjF/

```
   #div1 {
       height: 300px
       overflow: auto;
       overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    #div2 {
        background-color: #ccc;
        min-height: 300px;
    }
```

This way, div2 will scroll within div1 even if the content exceeds the height of div1 (on the fiddle, i gave div2 a height of 600px).

Comment: no, i don't need a fixed height for div2. i need it to fit the whole div1's height even if you put 1000px of content in it.

Answer (score 0):

i made a slight modifications.. Hope you will understand this..

**html**

```
<div id="div1">
     <div id="div2">
         Content in div2.
     </div>
    <p id="p3">
        ajs hask jas ashja sjh jasj ashja sbasj hasbk asj ask ashja sba sjh ashj asb sajask ajhb sakjbs ashjb saasj
    </p>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var div3height=$('#div3').height();
    $('#div2').height(div3height);
});
```

**css**

```
    #div1 {
       border:1px solid #ff0000;
       height: 150px;
       overflow: auto;
       overflow-x: hidden;
       width:150px;
    }

    #div2 {
        background-color: #ccc;
        height:100%;
        overflow:auto;
        float:left;
        width:50%;
    }
    #p3 {
        height:auto;
        overflow:auto;
        float:left;
        width:50%;
}
```

hope  this will help you..

**EDIT**

in case if the question was meant as stated by Ipd

then you just need to change the css and leave the jquery part...

ie..

**css**

```
#div1 {
       border:1px solid #ff0000;
       height: 150px;
       overflow: auto;
       overflow-x: hidden;
       width:150px;
       background-color: #ccc;
    }

    #div2 {
        height:100%;
        overflow:auto;
        float:left;
        width:50%;
    }
    #p3 {
         background-color:#FFF;
        height:auto;
        overflow:auto;
        float:left;
        width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Given the user is trying to avoid javascript for the task, presumably because they want their page to operate fully for visitors with javascript turned off, importing a whole library for this minor task alone is quite over the top...

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jPMjF/21/)**

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        Content in div2.
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aspernatur, sequi, non mollitia ducimus eaque commodi iure vel quos ipsam hic voluptatem tempore facere quo dolorum magnam incidunt porro quis culpa.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container {
   background-color: #fff;
   border: 1px solid #ff0000;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#div1 {
    background-color: #fff;
   border:1px solid #ff0000;
   height: 100px;
   overflow: auto;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   width:200px;
}

#div1 p { display: inline-block; width: 50px; }

#div2 {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: auto;
    width: 100px;
    padding-bottom:80%;
    float:left;
}
```

Your answer check this its work 100%